# Persistent Connections in an ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I developed a web service (asmx) that is used to expose a proprietary system.

To send messages to my system I create a connection that is very expensive so I'd like to create this connection object once to reuse as many times as possible.

How to survive to web service lifecycle to achieve my goal?

Usually (in normal Windows application) the object is stored in a static variable.

Comment: Switch to WCF and then you can host it in a Windows Service. This could be a lot of work, or perhaps not depending on how you have written your web service.

Comment: @marc_s sorry, I meant proprietary :)

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @keith Paine: I "must" use IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Object-pool** pattern is your friend here. A pool contains a number of already created objects that are returned to the pool after used. On the other hand, instead of creating a new object, a one from the pool is taken if available.

There are number of different implementations easily googlable, find one and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks! this sounds new for me. Could you explain better what you are talking about?

Comment: I saw that this case is mostly used for put n objects and use n objects. In my case only the first call will put the object and all the other clients will get the item many times (they will not "consume" it). Is this pattern tailored for my needs in your opinion?

Comment: Are you sure concurrent clients can reuse the same object? If not, let your pool be larger than just a single object and let clients always pick a currently unused object. And yes, object-pool can be used regardless of the number of objects in a pool.